# Transformation matrix between base and end effector in Staubli

Tags: robotic-arm, kinematics, transformation

I have a Staubli TX2-140. I want to know if the controller gives the transformation matrix between base link and end effector in the actual robot arm configuration or if I have to calculate it. I understand that Staubli software (Staubli Robotics softare) should give it.